# Docker - Load Balancing - assigning ports

Tags: docker, docker-swarm-mode

I've setup a docker swarm with 2 nodes, 1 manager and 1 worker. I have 1 docker image that runs a jetty server on port 8080. When I start the service on the manager node with 4 replicas, I see 2 containers spawned on each node. When I attempt to access my application from the browser on the individual hosts, I notice that the request is received only by 1 of the containers on each node.

Without the setup of an external load balancer(like HAProxy), is it possible to handle the requests in a round robin fashion between the containers on a given host - such that my first request goes to 1 container and the next request goes to the other container on the same host?

Thanks

Comment: Please share the exact command or docker-compose.yml that was used for the deployment.